# How to map Fields select option in redux form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, select-options

I tried to map an array so that I will not code a 200 codes in one particular select. This is my code.
const location = [ {id: 'A'}, ...... up to 200 id: values]

```
<FormControl fullWidth={true}>
    <Field name='location'
           component={renderSelectField}
           option={location.map((location, index) => (<option value={location.id}>{location.id}</option>))}
           props={{size: 'small',
                   type: 'text',
                   variant: 'outlined'
           }}
    />
 </FormControl>

const renderSelectField = ({input, label, meta: {touched, error}, children}) => (
    <Select
        floatinglabeltext={label}
        errortext={touched && error ? 1 : 0}
        {...input}
        onChange={(value) => input.onChange(value)}
        children={children}/>
);

 instead of coding these:


    {/*    <option/>*/}
    {/*    <option value='A'>A</option>*/}
    {/*    <option value='B'>B</option>*/}
    ..... up to 200
```

I tried also put a return in it but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to map it using MenuItem instead of Option in Field element

```
{Location.map((location, index) => (
       <MenuItem key={index} value={location.id}>
           {location.id}
       </MenuItem>
))}
```